# iOS Developer/Product Keys/Certificates Starting Again

Tags: ios, private-key, public-key, csr

Our iOS development and distribution iMac fried and we lost all of our iOS certificates and keys for development and releasing apps.

All the Apple documentation I can find either relates to using a machine thats already got the details within it - however we've got nothing.

Using our developer account how can we generate the CSRs/Private Keys/Public Keys/Certificates etc again without needing anything from the old install?

Thanks

Comment: As I remember new XCode version automatically do that for you. You(Admin) need just  approve requested certificates from member center.

Comment: what about private keys? Xcode would not be able to do this, because private keys are saved in mac. and it you don't have the private key then no certificate or profile work , Its a combination of public and private key. Xcode just play with public one.

Comment: From apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH5-SW3


 If you created a backup of your signing identities on this or another Mac, as described in Exporting Your Developer Profile, click the Import Developer Profile button to restore the private key in your keychain. Otherwise, click the “Revoke and Request” button to create a new signing identity.

Comment: So In our case it will create new signing identity, with new private key.

Comment: @IAmDav that's my point, 1+ for giving the official words on it.

Comment: So if you do not have a backup of the private keys xcode is unable to regenerate them for you? You'll have to run through a new process?

Comment: Yes. But may be Xcode 6 will present you wizard for this process , I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't generate the same CSRs/Private keys/Public etc.

You need to revoke all the certificates and profiles, generate new certificates from you new mac KeyChain Access. This should not harm any thing either published apps or in development.

Comment: This time should take a backup of all this certificate and PK stuff :) .